# Как реализовать проверку входных данных при нажатии кнопки?

Tags: c#, winforms

Хочу реализовать проверку корректности всех входных данных в поля регистрации и после нажатия на кнопку Registration, чтобы в методе проверялись все входные данные на корректность и далее шёл переход на форму Login.

Сами проверки на корректность у меня есть, но хочу реализовать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку вносились данные если все поля корректно заполнены и происходил переход на другую форму.

```
 public partial class Registration : Form
{

    public Registration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    #region registrButton
    private void registrationButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (check == true)
        {
            using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
            {
                User user = new User();
                user.Name = NameBox.Text;
                user.Surname = surnameBox.Text;
                user.Street = StreetBox.Text;
                user.Phone = phoneMaskedBox.Text;
                user.Town = TownBox.Text;
                user.Email = EmailBox.Text;
                user.Password = PasswordBox.Text;

                db.Users.Add(user);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            Login login = new Login();
            login.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Check all dates");
        }


    }
    #endregion

    // bool value
    #region checkvalues
    bool check = false;
    #endregion

    // Boxes
    #region nameBox
    private void NameBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            check = true;
        }
       else
        {
            check = false;

            e.Handled = true;
            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - the layout is not English";
            hint.Show("You can't enter a name using a different layout" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", NameBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
    }
    private void NameBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(NameBox);
    }
    private void NameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 1)
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text.ToUpper();
        ((TextBox)sender).Select(((TextBox)sender).Text.Length, 0);
    }
    #endregion

    #region surnameBox
    private void surnameBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            e.Handled = true;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - the layout is not English";
            hint.Show("You can't enter a name using a different layout" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", surnameBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
    }
    private void surnameBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(surnameBox);
    }
    private void surnameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 1)
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text.ToUpper();
        ((TextBox)sender).Select(((TextBox)sender).Text.Length, 0);
    }
    #endregion

    #region emailBox
    private void EmailBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        string pattern = @"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@))" +
            @"(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-0-9a-z]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$";


        if (Regex.IsMatch(EmailBox.Text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - Attempt to enter forbidden characters";
            hint.Show( "\nExample email adress: john@example.com" +
                "\nPress the key to hide this hint", EmailBox, 0, 20, 5000);
        }
    }
    private void EmailBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(EmailBox);
    }
    #endregion

    #region phoneBox
    private void phoneMaskedBox_MaskInputRejected(object sender, MaskInputRejectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (phoneMaskedBox.MaskFull)
        {
            check = false;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - Too much data";
            hint.Show("You can't enter any more data" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", phoneMaskedBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
        else if (e.Position == phoneMaskedBox.Mask.Length)
        {
            check = false;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected - End of Field";
            hint.Show("You can't add extra characters to the end of this date field." +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", phoneMaskedBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input Rejected";
            hint.Show("You can only add numeric characters (0-9) into this date field." +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", phoneMaskedBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
    }

    private void phoneMaskedBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (phoneMaskedBox.TextLength == 12)
            check = true;
        else
            check = false;
    }

    private void phoneMaskedBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(phoneMaskedBox);
    }


    #endregion

    #region passwordBox
    private void PasswordBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || (e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9') || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            e.Handled = true;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - the layout is not English or there was an attempt to enter forbidden characters";
            hint.Show("You can't enter a name using a different layout" +
                "\nCharacters are not allowed: !#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", PasswordBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }

    }
    private void PasswordBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(PasswordBox);
    }

    private void PasswordBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        check = false;

        if (PasswordBox.TextLength < 6 || PasswordBox.TextLength > 24)
        {
            inputincorrect.SetError(PasswordBox, "The password must contain between 6 and 24 characters");
        }
    }




    #endregion

    #region townBox
    private void TownBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            e.Handled = true;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - the layout is not English";
            hint.Show("You can't enter a name using a different layout" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", TownBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
    }

    private void TownBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(TownBox);
    }

    private void TownBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 1)
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text.ToUpper();
        ((TextBox)sender).Select(((TextBox)sender).Text.Length, 0);
    }


    #endregion

    #region streetBox
    private void StreetBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyChar >= 'A' && e.KeyChar <= 'Z') || (e.KeyChar >= 'a' && e.KeyChar <= 'z') || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            check = true;
        }
        else
        {
            check = false;

            e.Handled = true;

            hint.ToolTipTitle = "Input rejected - the layout is not English";
            hint.Show("You can't enter a name using a different layout" +
                "Press the key to hide this hint", TownBox, 0, -20, 5000);
        }
    }

    private void StreetBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        hint.Hide(TownBox);
    }

    private void StreetBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((TextBox)sender).Text.Length == 1)
            ((TextBox)sender).Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text.ToUpper();
        ((TextBox)sender).Select(((TextBox)sender).Text.Length, 0);
    }


    #endregion

    #region confirmBox
    private void confirmpassBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (confirmpassBox.Text != PasswordBox.Text)
        {
            check = false;
            inputincorrect.SetError(confirmpassBox, "Password don't match");
        }
        else
        {
            check = true;
            inputincorrect.Clear();
        }
    }

    #endregion


}
```

Пытался закостылить через булеву переменную, но костыль не прошёл

[Сам проект](https://github.com/Ezario/CourseWork-v0.0.1-)

Проект делаю на EF Core с использованием MS Sql

Comment: Мне так кажется,  что `NameBox_TextChanged()`, `surnameBox_TextChanged()`, `TownBox_TextChanged()`, `StreetBox_TextChanged` ваще одинаковые в принципе, можно же использовать всего один общий метод вместо четырех, тем более вы работаете не по имени текстбокса а через `sender`. `при нажатии на кнопку вносились данные если все поля корректно заполнены`, а сейчас не заполняются поля что-ли?

Comment: поля заполняются. Только не могу реализовать тему, что при нажатии на кнопку если какое-то из полей некорректно заполнено выбивало ошибку об этом и если поля заполнены корректно, чтобы переходило на новую форму. Нет идей как это реализовать. А за подсказку с методом спасибо, сейчас буду тогда переделывать)

Comment: @Bulson, или можно засунуть все проверки в один метод и этот метод возвращал true/false при вводе корректных/некорректных данных?

Answer (score 0):

Вот образец рабочей проверки. Метод всегда вызывается для проверки входных данных в поле

```
   public bool IsNameValid(string name)
    {
        bool valid = false;
        Regex check = new Regex(@"^([A-Z][a-z-A-z]+)$");
        valid = check.IsMatch(name);

        if (valid == true)
        {
            return valid;
        }
        else
        {
            return valid;
        }
    }

    private void nameBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextChange(sender, e);
    }

    private void nameBox_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsNameValid(nameBox.Text))
        {
            inputincorrect.SetError(nameBox, "Invalid name");
        }
        else
        {
            inputincorrect.SetError(nameBox, null);
        }
    }
```

Сама проверка на кнопке

```
if (IsNameValid(nameBox.Text) == true && // ещё проверки)
       {
            // какой-то код
        }
```